# How to bind the session to the User object using jersey

Tags: java, session, jersey, session-variables

I am trying to create login function and I want to save in the session specific data to use in future requests of the user is it possible?

In the loginUser, first if is always false even if the user already logged
and same in the updatePassword .

I need to save the attribute from the function `loginUserToSession`.  Any  idea why it doesn't  work ?

here is my code

**Resource**

```
    @Path("/logIn")
    @Singleton
    public class UserResource extends baseResource<UserDao, UserEntity>
    {
        @Path("/authenticateUser")
        @GET
        @UnitOfWork
        public String loginUser(@Context HttpServletRequest req @QueryParam("callback") String callback, @QueryParam("loginInfo") LoginInfo loginInfo) throws JsonProcessingException
        {
            if(SessionManager.isUserConnected(req))
            {
                return ResourceResponse.getResourceJsonString("null", callback, "true", ErrorMessageEnum.SUCCESS);
            }
            String userName = loginInfo.username;
            String plainTextPassword = loginInfo.password;
            UserEntity user = objectDao.logIn(userName, plainTextPassword);
            if(user != null)
            {
                SessionManager.loginUserToSession(req, user.getUserId(), userName);
                return ResourceResponse.getResourceJsonString(user.getUserStatus(), callback, "true", ErrorMessageEnum.SUCCESS);
            }
            return ResourceResponse.getResourceJsonString("null", callback, "false", ErrorMessageEnum.LOGIN_FAILED);
        }

    @Path("/updatePassword")
    @GET
    @UnitOfWork
    public String updatePassword(@Context HttpServletRequest req, @QueryParam("callback") String callback, @QueryParam("oldPwd") String oldPwd, @QueryParam("newPwd") String newPwd) throws JsonProcessingException
    {
        if(SessionManager.isUserConnected(req))
        {
            short userId = SessionManager.getUserId(req);
            ObjectDaoResponse res = objectDao.updatePassword(userId, oldPwd, newPwd);
            return ResourceResponse.getResourceJsonString(res.getObjectJsonString(), callback, res.getSuccess(), res.getCode());
        }
        else
        {
            return ResourceResponse.getResourceFailResponseString(callback, ErrorMessageEnum.USER_NOT_CONNECTED); 
        }
    }
}
```

**SessionManager.java**

```
    public static void loginUserToSession(HttpServletRequest req, short userId, String userName)
    {
        if(req == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        HttpSession session = req.getSession(true);
        session.setAttribute(ATTRIBUTE_USER_NAME, userName);
        session.setAttribute(ATTRIBUTE_USER_ID, userId);
        session.setAttribute(ATTRIBUTE_USER_CONNECTED, true);
    }

    public static boolean isUserConnected(HttpServletRequest req)
    {

        if(req == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        HttpSession session = req.getSession(false);
        if(session != null)
        {
            boolean userConnected = (boolean) session.getAttribute(ATTRIBUTE_USER_CONNECTED);
            if(userConnected)
            {
                 return userConnected;
            }
            System.out.Println("session.getAttribute(ATTRIBUTE_USER_CONNECTED)== null");
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that for some reason google postman don't send the HttpServletRequest as it should be. so jersey translate it like new user and create an empty new HttpServletRequest. **Conclusion do not test your server side with Google's postman**
when i try to send the request from my client it work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Please change into **Resource** like this:

```
public String loginUser(@Context HttpServletRequest req @QueryParam("callback") String callback, @QueryParam("loginInfo") LoginInfo loginInfo) throws JsonProcessingException
        {
            if(SessionManager.isUserConnected(req))
            {
                return ResourceResponse.getResourceJsonString("null", callback, "true", ErrorMessageEnum.SUCCESS);
            }else{
            String userName = loginInfo.username;
            String plainTextPassword = loginInfo.password;
            UserEntity user = objectDao.logIn(userName, plainTextPassword);
            if(user != null)
            {
                SessionManager.loginUserToSession(req, user.getUserId(), userName);
                return ResourceResponse.getResourceJsonString(user.getUserStatus(), callback, "true", ErrorMessageEnum.SUCCESS);
            }
          }
        }
```

Above was the flow error , whatever i got, Now you have to **setattribute into session scope** then use this:

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
session.setAttribute("UserName", "Usename_Value");
```

**Or for request Scope** use this:

```
request.setAttribute("attributeName",yourStringVAlue);
```

Comment: just "else" doesn't do the trick.. I wish it were that simple :)

Comment: the row  SessionManager.loginUserToSession(req, user.getUserId(), userName);,
 in the loginUser function doing just that  please see the part of SessionManager.java

Comment: "Returns the current HttpSession associated with this request or, if there is no current session and create is true, returns a new session."
 and we need new session if we got to this point and not returned in the   "if(SessionManager.isUserConnected(req))"

Comment: request.getSession(true); need to be with the param because:
"Returns the current HttpSession associated with this request or, if there is no current session and create is true, returns a new session."
 and we need new session if we got to this point and not returned in the   "if(SessionManager.isUserConnected(req))"